# ¿Cómo puedo guardar la dirección de una imagen en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

gracias por el apoyo hasta ahora, veran tengo un formulario para subir imagenes a una db el cual funciona correctameente pero mi profesor me dijo que tambien guarde la dirección del archivo puesto que al borrar la imagen tambien se elimine del lugar donde esta alojada. Lo que entendí fue que al guardar la dirección la imagen se guardara ademas de en la db, en una carpeta de la pc (localhost) pero no he logrado hacerlo.

Este es el formulario

```
<form action="insertarimg.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="imagen"><h3>Imagen</h3></label>
    <input type="text" required name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
    <input type="text" required name="descripcion" id="descripcion" placeholder="Descripcion">
    <input type="file" required name="imagen" id="imagen">
    <input type="submit" name="subir" value="Subir Imagen">
   </form>
```

Insertar Imagen

```
inlude ('conexion.php');
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
$imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']));
$query = "INSERT INTO imagenes(nombre, descripcion, imagen) VALUES ('$nombre', '$descripcion', '$imagen')"; 
$resultado = $conexion->query($query);
if($resultado){
echo"<script type='text/javascript'>;
alert ('El archivo se subio correctamente');
window.location='eliminar.php';
</script>";
}else {
    echo"<script type='text/javascript'>;
alert ('Error al subir el archivo');
window.location='eliminar.php';
</script>";
```

Aquí muestro la imagen

```
<table border="2">
<thead>  
<tr>
<th>Nombre</th>
<th>Imagen</th>
<th>Operaciones</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
include('conexion.php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM imagenes";
$resultado = $conexion->query($query);
while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){

?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></td> 
<td><img height="200px" src="data: imgage/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['imagen']); ?>"></td>

 <td><a href="borrarimg.php">Eliminar</a></td>
</tr> 
<?php
            }
?>
</tbody>  
</table>
```

Por favor si pueden apoyarme, gracias.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81422/discussion-on-question-by-eduardo-como-puedo-guardar-la-direccion-de-una-imagen).

Answer (score 1):

Aunque la gente se queje de que una base de datos con imágenes almacenadas puede crecer mucho y niega la utilidad de ello, es cierto que es mucho mas practico y seguro hacerlo de esta según en que caso: 
Si lo que se busca es almacenar y no volver a tocar dichas imágenes es decir ningún cambio si que se recomienda almacenarlo en los ficheros sin embargo si dichas imágenes van a ser modificadas o tratadas constantemente se recomienda el almacenamiento de estas en la base de datos.

- Para alamacenar imagenes en carpetas tienes que asegurarte en todo momento de que los permisos esten correctos, lo que supone mas trabajo.
- A la hora de mover de directorio el proyecto o la aplicación, debes asegurarte de que las rutas de guardado y lectura de la imagen estén correcto(*Es posible hacerlo con funciones las cuales tengan la dirección en una variable lo cual también incluye mas trabajo*)  lo cual concluye a mas trabajo y responsabilidad
- Las imágenes almacenadas fuera del directorio del proyecto conllevan el tener que estar pendiente de su localización en todo momento y las imágenes almacenadas en el mismo proyecto tiene problemas de seguridad ya sin el correcto tratamiento de los permisos pueden ser accesibles por cualquier usuario en todo  momento a través de la URL
- Un argumento suele ser que la base de datos sube de tamaño, bueno el directorio también lo hace por lo que si hablamos de almacenamiento en cualquier caso aumentara por lo que llega a ser lo mismo.

Mi recomendación es que las mantengas en la base de datos en una tabla solo para las imágenes y listo, de esta forma obtienes mas seguridad ya que solo tu accedes a la base de datos y es mas fácil de manejar.

> En uno de los proyectos el profesor nos mando hacer lo mismo, almacenar las imágenes en local, pero la cantidad de imágenes que tuvimos que almacenar se nos fue de las manos, hablamos de miles de imágenes para un pequeño proyecto, el tema de guardar la posición de cada imagen en la base de datos, que el nombre coincida, los permisos, la migración,etc fue un horror.
> Por mi parte a menos que te sea obligatorio me sigue pareciendo mucha mejor practica el mantenerlas en la ase de datos.

En este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)( aunque este en ingles) tratan mas a fondo este tema, y en algunas de las respuestas puedes ver la diferencia de cuando usar cada metodo.
Y [en este](https://www.quora.com/Difference-in-storing-image-in-database-table-vs-storing-image-in-folder-and-save-its-path-in-database-Which-is-better-and-why-PHP) listan algunos casos en los que es mas practico y el porque

Comment: además te recomiendo leer [answer] pues esto parece mas un comentario/opinión que una respuesta, lo cual hace que debería ir en la zona de comentarios

Comment: Estaría bien que antes de recomendar a otros a leerlo lo haga uno mismo: `Cualquier respuesta que encamine a los lectores en la dirección correcta ayudará siempre y cuando menciones limitaciones, supuestos, o simplificaciones en tu respuesta.`

Comment: Como bien he dicho, en ningún momento he roto ninguna regla, de hecho la cita arriba escrita proviene el mismo link que tu me has pasado y que me da la razón pero al parecer ni siquiera lo has leído, Solo añado mi opinión/consejo al final con lo cual no es completamente un comentario. Lo que menciono en mi respuesta no es incorrecto el donde almacenar los datos varia según como los vayas a usar, por mucho que crezca la base de datos si estas imágenes van a ser para acceder a ellas o modificaras es mas recomendable la practica de guardarlos en la base de datos

Answer (score 0):

Cuando cargas cualquier archivo al servidor, este se carga a una carpeta temporal, con un nombre temporal. Estos archivos no son accesibles por los usuarios que visiten tu sitio.

Lo que debes hacer con el archivo que procesa el request, debes tomar el archivo temporal y moverlo a una carpeta publica que sea visible por tus usuarios.

En el siguiente ejemplo, se asume que tienes una carpeta llamada "uploads" en tu carpeta root de tu aplicación web.

```
$dir_subida = '/var/www/uploads/';
$imagenRuta = $dir_subida . basename($_FILES['imagen']['name']);
$imagenNombre = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
$imagenValida = false;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'], $imagenRuta)) {
     $imagenValida = true;
}

// Si la imagen se cargo de forma correcta, entonces insertas en tu base de datos.

if($imagenValida) {
   $query = "INSERT INTO imagenes(nombre, descripcion, imagen) VALUES ('$nombre', '$descripcion', '$imagenNombre')"; 

   // Colocar codigo para insertar el registro en la base de datos
}
```

Luego para acceder a tu imagen, debes cambiar el path, ya que en tu ejemplo, si guardas el nombre del archivo, debes colocar la ruta (path) en el atributo src del tag IMG:

```
<img height="200px" src="uploads/<?php echo $row['imagen']; ?>" />
```

Comment: La carpeta debo crearla en la ubicación donde tengo los archivos?

Comment: La carpeta la debes crear en una ubicación que sea visible para tus usuarios... por lo general donde tienes tu archivo index.php puedes crear una carpeta con nombre uploads... Puedes colocarle una imagen de prueba y ver si esta accesible desde el explorador de internet...Ejemplo http://tudominio.com/uploads/imagendeprueba.jpg

Comment: cree la carpeta uploads y le añadi una imagen la cual pude visualizar en la siguiente direccion http://localhost/proyecto/uploads/images-2.jpeg entonces añadi la ruta al codigo:  /localhost/proyecto/uploads/ 
 pero mandaba tablas de error asi que la cambie por esta : C:\wamp64\www\Proyecto\uploads' y si sube la imagen pero no aparece en la carpeta uploads

Comment: Las rutas son diferentes en entorno windows y linux, estuvo bien el soporte que te diste a ti mismo. Cuando me dices que si sube la imagen, es que la puedes ver si entras a C:\wamp64\www\Proyecto\uploads?

Comment: No, manda el mensaje de que se subio correctamente y verifico en la db y si esta pero en C:\wamp64\www\Proyecto\uploads no esta. No se si se necesita crear otro campo en la tabla para la dirección o en el campo de imagen se mostraria la ruta? por cierto cambie el campo imagen de longblog a varchar

Comment: Que ruta se guardo en la base de datos?