# PHP: Subir una imagen a una base de datos

Tags: php, html, imagen, blob

En este momento estoy trabajando en un proyecto en PHP. Soy básicamente nuevo y tengo muchas dudas, entre las cuales está la siguiente:

**¿Cómo hago para subir una imagen a una base de datos usando `long_blob`?**
Cabe destacar que tengo dos botones, uno para enviar datos a una tabla, y otra para subir la imagen a otra tabla.

Ejemplo de mi código:

`Evidencia`

```
//Se escoge el archivo
<input type="file" name="Evidencia" value="Evidencia">

//Botón para enviar imagen
<input type="submit" name="SubirEvidencia" value = "Subir">

//Boton para subir datos(Irrelevante, pero vale la pena mencionarlo, ya que no estoy usando formulario.
<input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Enviar">

if ($_POST['SubirEvidencia']) {
   $fecha= $_POST['Fecha'];
   $imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['Evidencia']['tmp_name']));
   $query= "INSERT INTO evidencia_dia(id_promotor, fecha, evidencia) 
   VALUES ('$idPromotor','$fecha', '$imagen')";
   $resultado = $conn->query($query);
?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   alert("Se añadió imagen correctamente.");
   </script>
   <?php
}
```

Lo extraño de este código, es que si sube tanto el `id_promotor` como la fecha, pero no me sube el archivo. ¿Me podrían ayudar?

Comment: Yo por mi parte te recomiendo que guardes el nombre de la imagen y la imagen(archivo) la guardes en una carpeta para después solo colocar la url y concatenar el nombre de la imagen que traerás de la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Me podrías ayudar explicándome esto mas a detalle?

Comment: En una base de datos no se pueden subir archivos, en el servidor si. Por ende tenés dos opciones, o subís la imagen al servidor o bien encodeas en base64 la imagen y la subis a la DB.

Comment: Te recomiendo subir la imagen a una carpeta y en la base de datos solo guardes el nombre de la imagen, como dice  - Sebastián Lagos Yañez - en este enlace puedes ver un ejemplo de como hacerlo http://php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Quizás este link te pueda ayudar, se explica como subir una imagen al servidor y guardar la ruta en la bd. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/185396/cómo-puedo-guardar-la-dirección-de-una-imagen-en-mysql

Answer (score 1):

El input de nombre `SubirEvidencia` no esta reconocido en tu codigo como una variable para ser almacenada en tu base de datos, si requieres guardar la informacion desde tu formulario directamente en la BD tienes 2 opciones:
**La primera opcion**

> No olvides colocar tus input dentro de las etiquetas `<form>`

Recuperas el contenido de tu input en una variable de nombre imagen algo como esto:

```
$imagen = base64_encode($_REQUEST['SubirEvidencia']);
```

query no deberia de darte errores

**La segunda opcion**
Puedes utilizar la herramienta **summernote** [Disponible aqui](https://summernote.org/) que es una biblioteca JavaScript y te permitira hacer que tu input posea una herramienta de incrustar imagenes en su respectivo contenido, y si requieres almacenar la imagen en una columna aparte puedes perfectamente hacerlo desde tu PHP extrayendo el contenido que estara codificado en base64.

> Toma en cuenta que en tu base de datos debes configurarla como long_blob ya que es la que te permitira aceptar las largas cadenas de texto que se generan de la codificacion en base64

Espero sea de utilidad mi respuesta.